# Detecting toast messages with AccessibilityService

Tags: android, toast

I built an app which uses [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html) to track every Toast message which shows up at any time [as shown there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659734/detecting-toast-messages); just by logging their package name and message but the thing is, at the same time a use another app which also uses the same AccessibilityService, and therefore they don't work properly, they don't work at the same time; I can use one of them but not both at the same time. Is it possible to build such logging app, that uses Acc.Serv. but both apps won't interfere to each other? My question comes down to maybe more generous question, is it possible to create few apps which will use the same android service?