# How to determine if there is any toast being displayed in android

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-toast

Is there a way to check if there is a toast message being displayed in android?
I am writing an idlingResource and I want to make sure no toast is currently being displayed before I return the resource as being idle.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10665625/7915814) out

Answer (score 0):

> Create Custom toast.

```
private Toast myToast = nuul; // Create class Level Object to
```

> Add this code in the method

```
String message = "Your Message";
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
     the                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_container));

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_text);
text.setText(Message);

myToast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
myToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
myToast.setView(layout);
myToast.show();
```

> custom_toast.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_toast_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#80000000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_toast_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

> Dismiss the Toast, if it is not null

```
 if (myToast != null) 
  myToast.cancel(); // Dismiss the toast
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but in my case, I need to be able to detect system wide toasts I.e toasts produced even by other apps too

Comment: Do you have the id of toasts, which are produced in other apps?

Comment: do you check the comment by LieForBananas below your question? I thick it will help you.